# Is there a way to manually disable the key shortcuts for Chrome's developer tools shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Chrome thought it would be a really creative idea to have two different ways to tab between Developer tool panels. The traditional way, which is `[` + a number. And in the latest release, decided to overwrite the core functionality of Chrome so that if your developer tools are open and you want to tab to different tabs by doing Command + a number, it now just tabs through your developer tools as well. Not the most genius decision on their part. And I've brought it up to them, but they're probably busy building a space elevator to worry about usability in their browser.

Does anyone know how to disable this functionality? All hacks are absolutely welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue. Unfortunately I don't have a fix for you. Best you can do is contribute to the Group discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/1W9moW5ZlHw/agPcCFIiuRsJ

As well star and comment on the bug filled:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174606

Comment: Already did. Like two passing ships at night.